# Resetting reference level under contr.sum

Tags: r

How do I change the reference level under when contrasts are set to `contr.sum` `contr.poly`?

Toy data

```
df <- data.frame(id = rep(1:5, 4),
                 group = rep(c("A","B"), 10),
                 time = factor(rep(paste0("time", 1:4), each = 5)),
                 score = c(rnorm(5, 0 ,1),
                           rnorm(5, 4, 1),
                           rnorm(5, 8, 1),
                           rnorm(5, 12, 1)))
df
```

Now if you check the contrasts for the `time` variable you see each level of time is compared to the reference level, which is `time1`

```
contrasts(df$time)
```

If we change to `contr.sum` to get effects coding via

```
options(contrasts = c("contr.sum", "contr.poly"))
```

Now every other level is compared to `time4`

```
contrasts(df$time)
```

How do I change this contrast matrix so that levels 2-4 are compared to level 1, while still preserving the sum-to-zero effects coding?

Comment: Do you mean like `contrasts(factor(df$time, levels=levels(df$time)[4:1]))` ?

Comment: Yes that works. but I think I need to go back to school to understand these contrast matrices in the first place.

Comment: actually @thelatemail the code you supplied *does* reorder the reference levels, however it also resets the contrast matrix to `contr.treatment`. I don't suppose you know how to re-order the reference levels while still preserving the deviation coding used by `contr.sum`? If you make it an answer you get an upvote and a closed question.